# how to make a balanced fraction

Tags: fractions

Consider:

```
\begin{equation*}
\frac{x}{\left\Vert x \right\Vert_1}
\end{equation*}
```

produces:

[image: actual appearance]

Yet, what I actually want is to have both **x**s symmetrical to the fraction:

[image: shorter bar]

or even with a larger fraction line:

[image: longer bar]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest was is to move the subscript outside of the `\frac{}{}`:

```
\frac{x}{\left\Vert x \right\Vert}_{\!1}
```

and a little negative thinspace for better spacing.  The second option can be achieved with a careful use of `\makebox` and `\hphantom`:

[image]

## Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\WideAs}[2]{\makebox[\widthof{$#1$}][c]{$#2$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{x}{\left\Vert x \right\Vert}_{\!1}
    \quad
    \frac{\WideAs{\left\Vert x \right\Vert}{x}\hphantom{{}_1}}{\left\Vert x \right\Vert_1}
\end{equation*} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Package `mathtools` provides the command `\mathrlap` to write something to the right in math mode without allocating the space.

LaTeX's `\hphantom` can also be used in math mode to reserve horizontal space without typesetting the argument. For version with the long fraction line, an invisible subscript is put to the left.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
  \frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert\mathrlap{_1}}
  =
  \frac{x}{\hphantom{_1} \lVert x\rVert_1}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The length of the fraction bar can be controlled by adding symmetrical space:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  &\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert\mathrlap{_1}}
  =
  \frac{x}{\,\lVert x\rVert\mathrlap{_1}\,}
  =
  \frac{x}{\>\lVert x\rVert\mathrlap{_1}\>}
  =
  \frac{x}{\:\lVert x\rVert\mathrlap{_1}\:}
\\
  &\frac{x}{\hphantom{_1}\lVert x\rVert_1}
  =
  \frac{x}{\!\hphantom{_1}\lVert x\rVert_1\!}
  =
  \frac{x}{\!\!\hphantom{_1}\lVert x\rVert_1\!\!}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

In the first case the subscript is decouple with the previous fence, because it is the in `\mathrlap`. The following example, fixes this by setting the denominator twice. The first time with the subscript, but the complete expression in `\mathclap` so that the subscript is right after the fence. The second time the denominator is set without the subscript in `\hphantom` for the space.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\begin{document}
\[
  \frac{a}{             \mleft\lVert\frac{b}{c}\mright\rVert\mathrlap{_1}}
  =
  \frac{a}{   \mathrlap{\mleft\lVert\frac{b}{c}\mright\rVert_1}
              \hphantom{\mleft\lVert\frac{b}{c}\mright\rVert}}
  =
  \frac{a}{\hphantom{_1}\mleft\lVert\frac{b}{c}\mright\rVert_1}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- Package `mleftright` is used for `\mleft` and `\mright` that use `\left` and `\right` but without the additional horizontal spacing.
- `\lVert` and `\rVert` denotes that the `\lVert` is used as left fence and `\rVert` serves as right delimiter.