# How to make this fraction balanced?

Tags: amsmath, fractions

I want to balance this fraction  `\frac{2.5^{13.6}}{100} \sim 2700`. Without any modifications, the numerator 2.5 goes too far left and the balance is with the numerator and exponent combined .

[image]

I tried approach given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434254/how-to-make-a-balanced-fraction) using `mathtools`, but in this case the exponent goes over the sim sign. How can I achieve a balance between the numerator and denominator, with exponent appearing neatly (not over the `\sim`)?

MWE attached.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}%
\frac{2.5^{13.6}}{100} \sim 2600
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}%
\frac{2.5\mathrlap{^{13.6}}}{100} \sim 2600
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my opinion: It doesn't seem desirable to make the solidus longer anyway, as it would extend too much to the left.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish, but what you have posted is perfectly normal (i.e. the first case). If you would like to push it a bit right, you can do $\frac{\ \ \ 2.5^{13.6}}{100} \sim 2600$ and the fraction horizontal bar will be wider.

Comment: What the math meaning you are trying to express? In your second fraction above, independently from the operator position, I have doubt if you mean 2.5^13.6/100 or (2.5/100)^13.6....

Comment: The numerator is `2.5^{13.6}`, not `2.5`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, the numerator is 2.5<sup>13.6</sup> and the fact that a part has larger size glyphs is an accident of notation (that has been established for a few centuries). You wouldn't ask if that number got to be denoted as, say, exp(13.6; 2.5).

Typographic balance should always keep into account not hindering readability and keeping the *meaning*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

The standard way to print the statement
\[
\frac{2.5^{13.6}}{100}\sim 2600
\]

The nonstandard way
\[
\settowidth{\dimen0}{$2.5$}
\settowidth{\dimen2}{$100$}
\settowidth{\dimen4}{$^{13.6}$}
\setlength{\dimen0}{\dimeval{\dimen4-(\dimen2-\dimen0)/2}}
\frac{2.5^{\mathrlap{13.6}}}{100}\hspace{\dimen0}\sim 2600
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The nonstandard way seems like what you'd like to print, but it's

1. against established conventions in force since a few centuries;
2. ambiguous, because the exponent might be thought to refer to the whole fraction 2.5/100.

Comment: I fully support @egreg. Mathematical notation should aim at unambiguity first, rather than "(subjective) aesthetics". At least when there are two options to choose and the numerator is certainly 2.5^{13.6} and not 2.5.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.